# Total Financial exposure per year for warranty in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, finance

I'm on [SQL Server 2019](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-2019).

I'm stuck in a problem that seems to be quite simple, but I'm stuck.

I need to create a view in SQL that calculates the total financial exposure for warranty of our projects per year.

Each project has multiple warranty terms (but they don't matter for this calculation). I'm interested only in the financial exposure for the whole company.

The example table is:

| Project number | Warranty term | Financial exposure | Warranty period start | Warranty period end |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Project 1 | painting | 1,000,000 | 01-Jan-2021 | 01-Jan-2023 |
| Project 2 | structure | 500,000 | 15-May-2021 | 15-May-2031 |
| Project 3 | painting | 1,000,000 | 25-Mar-2022 | 24-Mar-2042 |
| Project 3 | performance | 5,000,000 | 25-Mar-2022 | 25-Mar-2030 |
| Project 4 | uptime | 10,000,000 | 01-Jan-2023 | 01-Jan-2033 |

I'm looking for something like:

| Year | Financial Exposure |
| --- | --- |
| 2021 | 1,500,000 |
| 2022 | 7,500,000 |
| 2023 | 17,500,000 |
| 2024 | 16,500,000 |
| 2025 | 16,500,000 |
| 2026 | 16,500,000 |
| 2027 | 16,000,000 |
| 2028 | 16,000,000 |
| 2029 | 16,000,000 |
| 2030 | 16,000,000 |
| 2031 | 11,000,000 |
| 2032 | 11,000,000 |
| 2033 | 11,000,000 |
| 2034 | 1,000,000 |
| 2035 | 1,000,000 |
| 2036 | 1,000,000 |
| 2037 | 1,000,000 |
| 2038 | 1,000,000 |
| 2039 | 1,000,000 |
| 2040 | 1,000,000 |
| 2041 | 1,000,000 |
| 2042 | 1,000,000 |

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need a tally table. Or generate one on the fly in your query using recursive cte. `CROSS JOIN` your project table to the tally table

---

```
with years as   -- the tally table
(
     select year = min(year(period_start)), max_year = max(year(period_end))
     from   project
     union all
     select year = year + 1, max_year
     from  years
     where  year < max_year
)
select y.year, sum(exposure) As [Financial Exposure]
from   project p
       cross join years y
where  year(p.period_start) <= y.year
and    year(p.period_end) >= y.year
group by y.year
```

---

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=71da2cc05ae35d90ed1ca043f425167c)

Comment: I'm no expert in sql and I'm struggling to create a view out of your solution... could you help me further? thanks again

Comment: just add `CREATE VIEW {view name} AS` in front of the query

Comment: I'm so dumb... I tried that and didnt work... now I tried again and worked... thanks again!!!

Comment: `cross join... where ` is silly, just use a normal join. Also I would venture to say it's not worth messing about taking `min` and `max` years from the table, just start with sensible defaults, say `2020` and `2050`, you're joining anyway